# Pandas format csv data based on key

Tags: python, json, csv, pandas, dataframe

I have a big csv file (1 million+ lines) with data along the lines of

```
s, p, o
4931958, type,          CNV
4931958, sample_id,     683665
4931958, primary_Site,  haematopoietic_and_lymphoid_tissue
4931958, site_subtype,  NS
```

My end result is to format the data into json along the likes of

```
{
    "name": 4931958,
    "type": "CNV",
    "sample_id": "683665",
    "site_subtype":  "NS"
}
```

I did this using regular python loops and it took 4 hours to run. Im looking into python pandas to help with this. 
My problem here is that the pandas docs seem to be solely based around maths equations.
Im currently reading in the csv and using `groupby` to organise my data by `s` above, but then how do I merge the remaining columns into the format that I wanted.

I originally started out creating a `list` of `dicts`

```
lst = []
for row in df.itertuples():
    lst.append({"name": row[1], row[2]: row[3]})
```

and then creating a new dataframe based on this list but Im running into the same issue of merge the rows of the dataframe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try DataFrame.pivot().

Pivot and group on 's' which becomes the new index:

```
 df_pivoted = df.pivot(index='s',columns='p', values='o')
```

Add the index as a new column:

```
 df_pivoted['name'] = df_pivoted.index
```

Output as JSON in 'records' format:

```
 df_pivoted.to_json('output.json',orient='records')
```

JSON file should look like this:

```
[{"primary_Site":"haematopoietic_and_lymphoid_tissue","sample_id":"683665","site_subtype":"NS","type":"CNV","name":4931958}]
```

Comment: Ill give that a try this morning. Thanks

Comment: Brilliant. Thank you. I really need to learn pandas properly but on a tight schedule...